# Invoking \input without arguments/parameters

Tags: input, arguments

I am wondering what the effect is of invoking `\input` without any arguments/parameters followed by an empty line:

Code:

```
....
\input

....
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? (I get `d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex File ignored`),.

Answer (score 6):

The TeX primitive `\input` takes no brace group it parses the following tokens in (rare for TeX) an implementation-specific manner to find a filename, expanding tokens as necessary. In web2c based implementations (almost all current ones) that is a sequence of non white-space characters or spaces within `"`-quoted strings.

LaTeX wraps this in a definition which looks ahead for `{` and if it is there takes a brace group and discards the braces, adding a space at the end.

So

```
\input
```

Is the same as

```
\input{}
```

and inputs the file `.tex` (which the latex distribution includes to avoid a low level file not found error on this input)

Comment: `.tex` is also included in plain (if there is an empty line after the `\input`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but only because the file is distributed by latex and the latex input tree is in plains's default input path

Comment: I wasn't commenting the file, but that the primitive `\input` looks also for `.tex`. Your description sounds a bit as if this happens only with the latex wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what follows `\input`. If I run `tex zehrfeld`, where `zehrfeld.tex` is

```
\input

blank line above

\input
no blank line

\bye
```

I get the following console output:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)
(./zehrfeld.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex
File ignored)
! I can't find file `no'.
l.6 no 
       blank line
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

The reason is that the blank line is converted into `\par`, which under normal conditions is not expandable. Therefore the filename turns out to be empty in the first case and `.tex` is tried; it exists in the LaTeX tool distribution.

In the second case the space is again ignored and the file name stops at the space, so `no.tex` is looked for.

By the way, `\input\space story` does not look for a file with a leading space.

If you try with LaTeX, the same happens, because `\input` is redefined to look for a following `{` (eating spaces); if no open brace is found, the primitive `\input` is called. The test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\input

blank line above

\input
no blank line

\stop
```

produces

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./zehrfeld.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./zehrfeld.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex File ignored)
! I can't find file `no'.
l.9 no 
       blank line
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

What happens when a file with empty file name is looked for depends on your distribution and may also depend on the TeX implementation. The old TeXtures, for instance, first tried files *without* extension, because in the Macintosh  world(late '80s and '90s) file extensions were not used.

Final note: if `\par` is redefined, other things may happen: try with

```
\def\par{a\endgraf}

\input

blank line above

\input
no blank line

\stop
```

which looks for `a.tex` because the primitive `\input` does macro expansion until finding character tokens.